# Error in connecting to MySql through JSP

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have done everything that is needed in setting up MySql in a new environment, I'm always successful in transferring it to another PC. But now there is an error, the error says:

```
HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /include/database.jsp at line 4

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /include/database.jsp at line 4

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /include/database.jsp at line 4

    1: <%@ page import="java.sql.*;" %>
    2: 
    3: <%
    4: Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/bms", "root","");
    5: 
    6: Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
    7: Statement stmt1=con.createStatement();

    This is the whole code:
        <%@ page import="java.sql.*;" %>

        <%
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/bms", "root","");

         Statement stmt=con.createStatement(); 
         Statement stmt1=con.createStatement();
         Statement stmt2=con.createStatement();
         Statement stmt3=con.createStatement();
         Statement stmt4=con.createStatement();
         Statement stmt5=con.createStatement();

         ResultSet rs,rs1,rs2,rs3,rs4,rs5;

         PreparedStatement pstmt,pstmt1,pstmt2,pstmt3,pstmt4,pstmt5;

         %>
```

Comment: You have more of a stack trace to share?

Comment: Please learn to work with servlets. :-)

Comment: Remove the ; from the import

Comment: check your connection url "jdbc:mysql://localhost/bms", BTW usual format is jdbc:mysql://localhost:urportno/urdb

Comment: if you connect to the database in jsp like that without putting that in a try..catch and the connection fails, your database password might be exposed to the user (if you have showing the errors turned on in Tomcat)

Comment: Adding to what @Sandeep said, don't SQL (or really, and Java) code in JSPs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the MySQL connector jar to the classpath for the web app, so probably just copy the jar into the WEB-INF/lib folder.

I tried to recreate some of your page and got the 500 for the missing jar - after that - the connection was available, but I didn't actually run statements because you problem never got that far.